# Debugging Dllimport code

Tags: c#, dll, native

Is it possible to see/debug the code which C# compiler generates for methods with DllImport attribute? I tried stepping into a method defined with DllImport attribute inside the VS debugger but it does not allow me to do this. In the disassembly view I can see the call instruction to a particular address, but when I hit F11 key (step into) it just steps over it. I have "Enable native code debugging" checkbox checked in the project properties.

**UPDATE**

If I understand correctly, the compiler performs some operations when it sees the `DllImportAttribute` attached to a method. I couldn't find anything in the `DllImportAttribute` class documentation. The source code for `DllImportAttribute` class also has only a very basic class definition. In the debugger when calling an external function I can see a `call FFA0C0C8` assembly instruction and when I step into it, it moves immediately to the imported function body, but the imported function has a different address than FFA0C0C8. I couldn't change the disassembly view to this address. It looks like all the dll loading logic is inside this function, which debugger skips. I'm wondering if this is some library function or some function which was generated by the compiler?

Comment: I doubt that the VS debugger will let you debug that code.

Comment: @David Heffernan Should I use WinDBG for that?

Comment: Maybe, I don't know what's best.

Comment: You need the symbols for the DLL you want to debug. Otherwise you will only be able to use disassembly view even in WinDbg.

Comment: Do you have a project for the DLL you want to step in to as part of your solution?

Comment: @ Scott Chamberlain I do have the project for the dll, but it is in Delphi. So I don't have the debug information that is compatible with MS's.

Comment: Why do you need to debug this code in the first place? What problem are you trying to solve? Methods marked with the DllImport attribute are imported from unmanaged DLLs. Do you want to debug *into* the unmanaged DLL? Or do you want to debug how the runtime is resolving the call to the DLL behind the scenes?

Comment: @Cody Gray It's the second one: I want to see how does the runtime load the DLL.

Comment: Because it's not working properly? Or because you're just curious? The mechanism is actually very simple: it involves calls to the Win32 `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` functions, then a stack frame is built and some other housekeeping performed. That won't help you to debug problems, though, and I suspect neither will being able to step through the code in a debugger. It works exactly the same way every time. If it is breaking, it's because your function signature is incorrect. That's why I asked what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @Cody Gray I'm curious. Also it might be helpful when debugging problems with dll function parameters marshaling.

Comment: Not completely relevant to the actual question, but the discussion about debugging into a Delphi DLL, it's quite possible.  It's been a while since I've done so, but I think you need to "Include TD32 debug info" (under Project Options -> Linker) and Visual Studio understands that debug format.  Obviously you don't want to deploy the Delphi DLL with that embedded.

Comment: @Bryce Wagner VS does not understand this.

Comment: @Max  It took me a long time to remember the details of this, but now I recall what the TD32 was for: it was so a Delphi .dll could be debugged in Delphi when it was hosted by a .NET application.  Sorry for the wrong information...  You're correct that VS does not understand TD32.

Answer (score 1):

You can debug P/Invoke calls if you enable native debugging, and if you have the symbols and source for the dll.

If you are trying to step into a P/Invoke call into some Windows dll then you probably fail since you don't have the source code for the dll.

**EDIT**

If you meant that you want to debug the actual CLR code that does the marshalling and the actual native call to the dll, then the answer's no - I don't think that's possible.

Comment: [I don't think this is what he's looking for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888158/debugging-dllimport-code#comment22624642_15888158).